# Trying to parse POST response of unknown encoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, encoding

I am trying to parse a response from a post request with the following:

```
// PERFORM REQUEST
NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    // GET RESPONSE STRING
    responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    // SIGNAL DONE
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);

}];
```

I have been having issues with special characters such as `À` `È` `Ì` `Ò` `Ù` returning incorrectly. Is there a way I can determine the proper encoding of the data? Or decode the data with something that can properly interpret these characters?

Comment: You may check `[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields]` to check if there is an encoding.

Comment: @Larme It looks like nothing encoding related is coming through in the header

Answer (score 1):

If you have Umlauts, NSASCIIStringEncoding is definitely the wrong encoding, as that means original, 7-bit ASCII, and will fail for any byte with value > 127.

There is no universal way to determine a text‘s encoding. Depending on what the data is that you’re downloading, there might be a heuristic. E.g. if you know a string that is contained in all responses that contains international characters, you can compare that byte sequence to the same in various encodings. Or there are libraries that contain statistical information about the frequency of certain byte sequences to detect what language and encoding a text is, but those are just as likely to guess wrong.

You already said in a comment that there‘s no header indicating an encoding, which would be an alternative solution.

Beyond that, you can only look at the specification for whatever server you’re talking to and hard-code the encoding given there. Or if there is none, try out different encodings until one works.

The most common encodings these days are UTF8, and Windows Latin 1. If you can‘t tell until much later (e.g. parsing a JSON response), I‘d recommend using an encoding where any value from 0...255 is valid (like Windows Latin or non-lossy ASCII), and after examining the data, convert it again.

Comment: Thank you this really helped in finding a solution. I was able to split the data up into smaller portions and search and decode each chunk separately.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by using the following to detect the encoding of the data:

```
// FIND ENCODING
NSStringEncoding encoding = [NSString stringEncodingForData:chunk encodingOptions:nil convertedString:nil usedLossyConversion:0];
```

To improve it's accuracy I split the data up into chunks and individually decoded each chunk. The code used to do this is as follows:

```
// PERFORM REQUEST
NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    // INIT
    responseStr = @"";
    NSUInteger length = [data length];
    NSUInteger chunkSize = 100;
    NSUInteger offset = 0;

    do {

        // GET CHUNK
        NSUInteger thisChunkSize = length - offset > chunkSize ? chunkSize : length - offset;
        NSData* chunk = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:(char *)[data bytes] + offset
                                             length:thisChunkSize  freeWhenDone:NO];

        // SET OFFSET
        offset += thisChunkSize;

        // FIND ENCODING
        NSStringEncoding encoding = [NSString stringEncodingForData:chunk encodingOptions:nil convertedString:nil usedLossyConversion:0];

        // GET RESPONSE STRING
        NSString *chunkString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:chunk encoding:encoding];

        // APPEND TO RESPONSE
        responseStr = [responseStr stringByAppendingString:chunkString];

    } while (offset < length);

    // SIGNAL DONE
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);

}];
```

Comment: I'm not sure splitting it up is the right solution ... usually, the more text a heuristic gets, the better the result is (as some texts might consist of ambiguous byte sequences that are valid and common in several encodings) -- also, are you sure your requests can contain different encodings? Most APIs decide on a single encoding beforehand and consistently use that.

Comment: @uliwitness The api i'm accessing could possibly contain text in multiple languages. I'm not sure if there is an encoding I could use to decode all the text under the same rules? or maybe the issue is in how the AIP is implemented and is outside my control? I understand spliting it up like I did could cause a lot of problems, however I'm a little lost as to how I could improve it without changing the API.

Comment: Usually, if it could be multiple languages, anyone in their right mind (and not burdened by backwards compatibility) would use a Unicode encoding, like UTF8, UTF16 (big endian or little endian) or UTF32 (big endian or little endian). If it isn't Unicode and doesn't contain any indication of encoding or CodePage used (ISO/Windows have CodePages for different languages, which is basically just another name for encoding, just limited to the Windows/ISO family of encodings), the API is very badly designed.